# When syncing files between a MAC and a PC with Rsync, do I need to consider character code differences with --iconv?

Tags: bash, operating-system, rsync, utf

I am syncing files between a PC and MAC, always from the MAC.  Rsync is being used and I wonder should I consider using the --iconv option to account for any differences between the two systems?

I am new to the MAC and its BSD Unix operating system so have never had to consider this.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /Users/Chris/Desktop/Jobs
mount -t smbfs //username:password@IPaddress/Jobs /Users/Chris/Desktop/Jobs
rsync -av --delete /Users/Chris/Jobs/ /Users/Chris/Desktop/Jobs/
umount /Users/Chris/Desktop/Jobs
rmdir /Users/Chris/Desktop/Jobs
```

I would like exact copies of the synced folders but their are hundreds of files so it is hard to verify if there is a character set problem that needs to be addressed with rsync's -iconv option.

Comment: Everything is UTF-8 these days. Unless you have some ancient Windows-1252 stuff I wouldn't worry too much about it. Also not a programming question.

Comment: @miken32 A quick search suggested that NTFS is using UTF-16 not UTF-8. Also, there are still a lot of non-legacy tools that use other encodings. When I zip a file named `äöüß.txt` using Windows 10's File Explorer and open the zip under Linux I get the filename `ДФБс.txt`. I guess Windows encodes the names inside zip files with the same encoding it uses internally -- clearly this encoding is different from Linux' UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @Socowi good point I was thinking about file content, not file names.